# Inner join on a left join makes the left join behave as a inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

I have a two lookup tables that I want to inner join on each other, however I only want to left join on my data table.

```
select * from CLIENT
LEFT JOIN [ENTRY] 
    on [ENTRY].ENTRY_CODE = CLIENT.CLIENT_COUNTY
   and [ENTRY].ENTRY_RECD = 'A'
INNER JOIN [ENTRY_TYPES]
     on [ENTRY_TYPES].ENTRY_TYPES_FileRecordID = [ENTRY].ENTRY_TYPE
    and [ENTRY_TYPES].ENTRY_TYPES_CODE = 'COUNTY' 
    and [ENTRY_TYPES].ENTRY_TYPES_RECD = 'A'
  where CLIENT_RECD = 'A'
```

So if `ENTRY_TYPES_FileRecordID = ENTRY_TYPE` fails I do not want that `ENTRY` record to be available as a left join item for the join on to `CLIENT`.

The way the above code is written the left join on `ENTRY` is behaving like a inner join.

Comment: If you modify the `INNER JOIN` to allow the possibility of `NULL` values from `ENTRY`, and you don't break it again in the `WHERE`, all will be well.  Or just keep using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s after the first, since that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own as I was typing up the question, I needed to separate out the inner join as a sub-query

```
select * from CLIENT
left join 
(
    select ENTRY_CODE, ENTRY_NAME 
    from [ENTRY]
    inner join [ENTRY_TYPES] on ENTRY_TYPES_FileRecordID = ENTRY_TABLE
                            and ENTRY_TYPES_CODE = 'COUNTY' 
                            and ENTRY_TYPES_RECD = 'A'
    where ENTRY_RECD = 'A'
) as CountyLookup on CLIENT_COUNTY = ENTRY_CODE
where CLIENT_RECD = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found a solution yourself, but now you made it a subquery. You can also do this by moving some parts around in your original query and adding two brackets.

So this is just to show an alternative:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [CLIENT]
LEFT JOIN ([ENTRY] --opening bracket
        INNER JOIN [ENTRY_TYPES]
            ON [ENTRY_TYPES].[ENTRY_TYPES_FileRecordID] = [ENTRY].[ENTRY_TYPE]
                AND [ENTRY_TYPES].[ENTRY_TYPES_CODE] = 'COUNTY' 
                AND [ENTRY_TYPES].[ENTRY_TYPES_RECD] = 'A') -- closing bracket
    ON [ENTRY].[ENTRY_CODE] = [CLIENT].[CLIENT_COUNTY]
        AND [ENTRY].[ENTRY_RECD] = 'A'
WHERE [CLIENT_RECD] = 'A'
```

Comment: Interesting, does this modify the execution plan of the SQL or is this just a semantic difference?

Comment: Tested both ways, the version I did was better by 1% (according to the "Acutal Execution Plan" generated by Management Studio). Your version has a `Nested Loop (Left Outer Join)` where mine did a `Merge Join (Left Outer Join)` that I think made up the difference.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for sharing the outcome. Do you also have the profiler at hand? Any difference in reads/CPU? Just out of curiosity...